# How to make MUI Tab to have multiple routes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-router-dom

I'm trying to make a simple navigation component with Material UI, React Router v6 and TypeScript. I have `AppBar` component with `Tabs` inside, it looks like this:
[NavBar screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuUvl.png)

The layout component renders the `<Navigation />` component that contains what I mentioned above and the `<Outlet />` to render the component according to the current path.

The problem is that I have two components for user: one to view users (its like a table that lists the users) and the second is a screen to create users (routes are `"/secure/users"` and the other is `"/secure/userCreate"`). When I click on the "Users" tab, the userView component gets rendered, because as u can see in the code below, I have the tab

```
<Tab label="Users" value={routes[6]} to="/secure/users" component={Link} />
```

to match the user view route (`"/secure/users"`), but that component has a button to create a new user, it redirects you to `"/secure/userCreate"` , but that way MUI tab gives me an error because there is no `Tab` that matches that route.

So my question is, how can I make the Users tab stay selected when I'm in the userView component and then also be selected on user creation? Because I think that would need the tab to match both routes at the same time, `"/secure/users"` and `"/secure/userCreate"`, and I dont know how to do that or if its possible

Here's my code so far:

navigation.component.tsx

```
const routes = ["/secure/books", "/secure/offers", "/secure/products", "/secure/vacation", "/secure/others", "/secure/reports", "/secure/users"];

function useRouteMatch(patterns: readonly string[]) {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  for (let i = 0; i < patterns.length; i += 1) {
    const pattern = patterns[i];
    const possibleMatch = matchPath(pattern, pathname);
    if (possibleMatch !== null) {
      return possibleMatch;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

export const Navigation = (): ReactElement => {
  const permission = getPermission();
  const routeMatch = useRouteMatch(routes)
  const currentTab = routeMatch?.pattern?.path;

  return (
    <Container style={{ marginTop: 34}}>
      <AppBar 
        position="static" 
        style= {{ background: '#FFFFFF'}}
        elevation={0}
      >
        <Container maxWidth="xl">
          <Tabs 
            value={currentTab}
            aria-label="nav tabs example"
            variant="scrollable"
            scrollButtons="auto"
            sx={{ 
              '& .MuiTab-root': {
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: 600,
                lineHeight: '175%',
                letterSpacing: '0.15px',
                padding: '5px 0px 5px 0px',
                color: 'rgba(0, 54, 101, 0.6)',
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'column',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'flex-start',
                marginRight: 6.25,
                minWidth: 0,
              },
              '& .MuiTabs-indicator': {
                backgroundColor: "#01A3FE",
                },
              '& .Mui-selected': {
                color: "#01A3FE !important",
              }
              }}
          >
            <Tab label="Books" value={routes[0]} to="/secure/books" component={Link} />
            <Tab label="Offers" value={routes[1]} to="/secure/offers" component={Link} />
            <Tab label="Products" value={routes[2]} to="/secure/products" component={Link} />
            <Tab label="Vacation" value={routes[3]} to="/secure/vacation" component={Link} />
            <Tab label="Others" value={routes[4]} to="/secure/others" component={Link} />
            <Tab label="Reports" value={routes[5]} to="/secure/reports" component={Link} />
            {permission.isAdmin &&
            <Tab label="Users" value={routes[6]} to="/secure/users" component={Link} />}
            <span className="MuiTabs-indicator css-1aquho2-MuiTabs-indicator" style={{ left: 0, backgroundColor: '#EEEEEE'}}></span>
          </Tabs>
        </Container>
      </AppBar>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

layout.component.tsx

```
export const Layout = (): ReactElement => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navigation />
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Edit: Maybe to clarify a bit, I need the Users Tab to stay selected when I'm in both routes (`"/secure/users"` and `"/secure/userCreate"`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply check if the current `pathname` value is the `"/secure/userCreate"` path and set the `currentTab` value to equal that of the "Users" tab's URL path.

Example:

```
const Navigation = (): ReactElement => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  const permission = getPermission();

  let currentTab = pathname;
  if (pathname === "/secure/userCreate") {
    currentTab = "/secure/users";
  }

  return (
    <Container style={{ marginTop: 34 }}>
      <AppBar position="static" style={{ background: "#FFFFFF" }} elevation={0}>
        <Container maxWidth="xl">
          <Tabs
            value={currentTab}
            aria-label="nav tabs example"
            variant="scrollable"
            scrollButtons="auto"
            sx={{ .... }}
          >
            <Tab
              label="Books"
              value={routes[0]}
              to="/secure/books"
              component={Link}
            />
            <Tab
              label="Offers"
              value={routes[1]}
              to="/secure/offers"
              component={Link}
            />
            <Tab
              label="Products"
              value={routes[2]}
              to="/secure/products"
              component={Link}
            />
            <Tab
              label="Vacation"
              value={routes[3]}
              to="/secure/vacation"
              component={Link}
            />
            <Tab
              label="Others"
              value={routes[4]}
              to="/secure/others"
              component={Link}
            />
            <Tab
              label="Reports"
              value={routes[5]}
              to="/secure/reports"
              component={Link}
            />
            {permission.isAdmin && (
              <Tab
                label="Users"
                value={routes[6]}
                to="/secure/users"
                component={Link}
              />
            )}
            <span
              className="MuiTabs-indicator css-1aquho2-MuiTabs-indicator"
              style={{ left: 0, backgroundColor: "#EEEEEE" }}
            ></span>
          </Tabs>
        </Container>
      </AppBar>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit frosty-danilo-4vsl3t]

If you don't want to explicitly check the paths then create an object that maps a pathname value to a tab "key" value, use the tab "key" value in each tab.